# How to send data like NAME[]=value via POST request and simultaneously redirect user to 3rd party server?

Tags: 6, redirection, forms

I'm writing a custom module which needs to send data string like this: "CODES[]=xxx&NAMES[]=xxx" via POST to 3rdparty payment gateway AND redirect user there.

I've written a form to gather data from customer, but I can't use [] in form fields names, Drupal reports an error (an array instead of string) and quits.

I can post all data manually via drupal_http_request, but it doesn't redirects browser to needed URL. If I use drupal_goto after drupal_http_request, the data is lost and payment service doesn't recognize the user. If I include $request(my drupal_http_request)->result in a page, I get redirected to 404 page of my site with a non-existent URL (/order/checkout.php which has to be appended to payment server root and instead glues to my server root URL).

If I use $form['#redirect'] or $form['#action'] it posts fields names without "[]".

Question is, how can I append these square brackets after request is formed, but before it is sent?

Or how can I send data along with redirecting?

Will be very grateful for help, this problem is driving me nuts for a week now.

UPD My code:

```
    //a form
function mymodule_ask(&$form_state) {

 $form = array();

$form['#action'] = 'https://3rdpartysite.url/script.php';
$form['#method'] = 'post';

 $form['ORDER_PRICE[]'] = array(
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#title' => t('Amount'),
   '#size' => 10,
   '#required' => TRUE
 );

 $form['ORDER_PNAME[]'] = array (
   '#type' => 'radios',
   '#title' => t('Name'),
   '#options' => array('Avia' => 'Avia tickets', 'Other' => 'Other'),
   '#required' => TRUE
 );

 $form['submit'] = array (
   '#type' => 'submit',
   '#value' => t('PAY')
 );

return $form;
}

function mymodule_ask_submit {
    //in form submit function retrieving data from form values
    $requestar['ORDER_PNAME[]'] = $form_state['values']['ORDER_PNAME'];
    $requestar['ORDER_PRICE[]'] = $form_state['values']['ORDER_PRICE'] * 1.02;
    //forming an array to post
    $onestr = '';
    foreach ($requestar as $key => $value) {
    $onestr .= $key."=".$value."&";
    }
    $resstr = chop($onestr, '&');
    // and then I tried different ways

    //either creating and auto-submitting a form with needed values
    create_form($requestar); //separate function creating this form
    drupal_execute('payu_addform', $form_state);
    // but it doesn't pass drupal evaluation because of "ORDER_PRICE[]" element name

     //or via http_request
    $result = drupal_http_request('https://PAYMENT_SERVER_URL/script.php',  array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'), 'POST', $resstr);
    drupal_set_message($result->request);

    // but it takes me to MY_SERVER_URL/order/checkout.php?CART_ID=442bc42170616cd36dfd2246434d4210, while I need it to make to PAYMENT_SERVER_URL/order/checkout.php?bla-bla-bla
    //may be I can use $result->request in some other way? Just printing within this submit function gives nothing... But how can I pass it to make drupal take me out?

}
```

Comment: You can't, that's not how HTTP works. Only browser can send POST data to a server. Your server-side code cannot. Only thing you can do is to set form's target to have values sent directly to 3rd party server.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: If you want the redirect to go to the _result_ page on the remote site, as if the form had been submitted on that site originally, the `$form['#action']` method is the only possible solution.

Comment: @Clive well, he could also let action stay as it was, and on a result page on his site create hidden form that would auto-POST to the target server with javascript, or offered button for graceful degradation. Not simple, not reliable, but can be done.

Comment: @Clive - Yes, that I understand perfectly, but how can I edit form-element names _after_ evaluation and _before_ submitting? This payment service accepts data strictly in given format, while Drupal can't allow it.

Comment: @Mołot - same thing, I've tried to make pre-populated form with all hidden values and auto-submit it, but the problem persists, NAME[] element can't be accepted by Drupal, even that it doesn't need to be processed or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the name directly:

```
$form['order_price'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Amount'),
  '#size' => 10,
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#name' => 'ORDER_PRICE[]',
);
```

Comment: I get exactly the same result with pre-populated hidden fields and text fields with default values. It just does what you'd expect. Do you have any modules installed that might interfere with form submissions?

Comment: I see that you succeeded. I can't. It just says that the form value is required. Syntax is the same.

Comment: Hmm, I'll think about modules. BTW, I'm on 6. What version of Drupal do you use?

Comment: Ah, that would be 7 :) I don't have a D6 install on this machine but I'm intrigued as to why this might not work so I'll get one set up and add a form. I think I know why from a high level but I'm just guessing until I can see it break. Could you edit the full form code into the question so I haven't got to write that out myself?

Comment: added form code. Thanks for giving me so much of your time!

Comment: No worries :) Before I install this site actually, could you just try the new answer? That might just do it

Comment: No, variant with ['#name'] => 'NAME[]' still produces same error - i.e. with actual form it says that this field is required (and doesn't take in my input)

Comment: Right, I has a good go with this and debugging the FAPI workflow - turns out this is pretty much by design in Drupal 6, changing it would require patching quite a lot of includes/form.inc to behave differently. I don't know if it's a bug, I couldn't find a similar report so maybe it's worth raising one on Drupal.org?

Comment: Thanks, Clive, for your conclusion! I don't have neither much time nor Drupal knowledge for such detailed debugging, you saved me lots of time. As to Drupal.org - I'll try, though I doubt they'll start changing abandoned 6th branch, it seems I'm the only one with such problem. I know that it can be done via OOP (I've seen the realization), form posting as an object's method.